# How does one iterate a JsonArray with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, system.text.json, jsonnode

I have JSON:

```json
{
    "dimensions": [
        {
            "name": "dim1"
        },
        {
             "name": "dim2"
        },
        {
             "name": "dim3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Loaded into JsonObject

```cs
JsonObject root = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString)?.AsObject();
```

And I wish to iterate a JsonArray with LINQ

```cs
var list =  root["dimensions"].GetEnumerator().Select(p => p["name"].GetValue).ToArray();
```

But get error

> CS1061: 'IEnumerator<JsonNode?>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerator<JsonNode?>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I find little when googling on JsonNode and LINQ. Perhaps not yet supported?

Comment: LINQ must operate on IEnumer**able** not on IEnumer**ator**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`AsArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.asarray?view=net-8.0) on node returned by `jsonNode["dimensions"]`:

```cs
var list = jsonNode["dimensions"].AsArray()
    .Select(node => node["name"].AsValue().GetValue<string>()) // or node["name"].ToString()
    .ToArray();
```